# ANTLR3: match everything until a specific keyword

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3

I am using ANTLR 3 to do the below.

Assume I have an SQL query. I know that in general it's WHERE, ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses are optional. In terms of ANTLR's grammar I would describe that like this:

```
query : select_clause from_clause where_clause? group_by_clause? order_by_clause?
```

The rule for each clause will obviously start with the respective keyword.

What I actually need is to extract each clause's contents as a string without dealing with its internal structure.

To do this I started with the following grammar:

```
query :
    select_clause from_clause where_clause? group_by_clause? order_by_clause?
EOF;

select_clause :
    SELECT_CLAUSE
;

from_clause :
    FROM_CLAUSE
;

where_clause :
    WHERE_CLAUSE
;

group_by_clause :
    GROUP_BY_CLAUSE
;

order_by_clause :
    ORDER_BY_CLAUSE
;

SELECT_CLAUSE : 'select' ANY_CHAR*;

FROM_CLAUSE : 'from' ANY_CHAR*;

WHERE_CLAUSE : 'where' ANY_CHAR*;

GROUP_BY_CLAUSE : 'group by' ANY_CHAR*;

ORDER_BY_CLAUSE : 'order by' ANY_CHAR*;

ANY_CHAR : .;

WS : ' '+ {skip();};
```

This one didn't work. I have had further attempts composing a correct grammar with no success. I suspect this task is doable with ANTLR3 but I am just missing smth.

More generally, I would like to be able to collect chars from the input stream into a single token until meeting a specific keyword that would indicate the beginning of a new token. This keyword should be the part of the new token.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding them to your tokens, why not move the `ANY_CHAR*` into parser rules instead? You could even "glue" these single tokens together using a rewrite rule.

A quick demo:

```
grammar T;

options { output=AST; }
tokens  { QUERY; ANY; }

query           : select_clause from_clause where_clause? group_by_clause? order_by_clause? EOF
                  -> ^(QUERY select_clause from_clause where_clause? group_by_clause? order_by_clause?)
                ;
select_clause   : SELECT_CLAUSE^ any;
from_clause     : FROM_CLAUSE^ any;
where_clause    : WHERE_CLAUSE^ any;
group_by_clause : GROUP_BY_CLAUSE^ any;
order_by_clause : ORDER_BY_CLAUSE^ any;
any             : ANY_CHAR* -> ANY[$text];

SELECT_CLAUSE   : 'select';
FROM_CLAUSE     : 'from';
WHERE_CLAUSE    : 'where';
GROUP_BY_CLAUSE : 'group' S+ 'by';
ORDER_BY_CLAUSE : 'order' S+ 'by';
ANY_CHAR        : . ;
WS              : S+ {skip();};

fragment S      : ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n';
```

If you now parse the input:

```
select JUST ABOUT ANYTHING from YOUR BASEMENT order by WHATEVER
```

the following AST would be created:

[image]

Trying to do something similar in your lexer would be messy, and would mean some custom code (or predicates) to check for keywords up ahead in the char-stream (both not pretty!).

Comment: Thanks Bart!

This grammar has some small problems (for instance if WHERE-clause contains 'or' operator) but you gave me an excellent starting point.
Since I am not yet very familiar with building an AST with ANTLR I will need to spend some time to fully understand the answer.